# How can I write a tab character in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

I tried using the tab key with the modifier keys, but I didn't get Safari to write a tab character in a text field shown in an HTML page.

Is it possible to do it? If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable the "Unicode Hex Input" input method from System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources and then type <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>.

Comment: Where do you enable this?

Comment: System Preferences / Language & Text / Input Sources.

Comment: Before anyone changes their main keyboard layout to Unicode Hex Input, note that [option-arrows and option-delete don't work work with it by default](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41657/use-option-arrows-with-unicode-hex-input), it is based on the U.S. keyboard layout and OS X doesn't come with versions of it for other keyboard layouts, and it removes dead keys like option-U for inserting umlauts.

Comment: This does not exist anymore (Mac OS 11).

Answer (score 19):

You can use control-option-tab.

In other applications you can use option-tab, but in Safari tab and option-tab are used to select elements in web views.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Its Safari only though (doesn't work on Chrome in OS X).

Answer (score 7):

Press Cmd-Alt-T to bring up "Special Characters..." in the Edit menu.

Search for "tab" and click Insert. You're looking for the one named "Character tabulation"

The website may not display it correctly,

```
but it will indent code.
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually wind up typing a tab in TextEdit or Stickies and copy-and-pasting it in Safari.

Comment: I use TextExpander.

Comment: Honestly this is the simplest, best answer. I couldn't get the other answers to work.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article titled [Control key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key) reports the following text:

> Under Mac OS X, the Control key allows the use of Emacs-style key combinations in most text entry fields. For example, Ctrl-A moves the caret to the start of the paragraph, Ctrl-L vertically centers the current line in the editing field, Ctrl-K cuts text to the end of the line to a kill ring separate from the normal clipboard, etc.

The table before that note reports that Ctrl-Q works as "Literal insert." I tried entering Ctrl-Q, Ctrl-I in Safari 5.0.4, and I get a tab in the text entry. 
It doesn't work on SE sites, as those combinations are used, respectively, to start a quoted text and emphasized text.

It doesn't seem to work on Safari 5.1, or Firefox 4.